# form goes in background

Tags: c#, winforms, compact-framework

I have a form, and doing showdialog on that. It is like msg box. I am doing something like

```
    msgBox = new MsgBox();
    if (msgBox.InvokeRequired)
    {
      msgBox.Invoke(new ShowMsg(ShowMessage));
    }
    else
    {
      ShowMessage();
    }
```

in show message i am doing Show Dialog. But the form goes in background of main form some times. please help on this.

Comment: What is exactly ShowMsg? A type that inherits Delegate?

Comment: Use the debugger.  You'll see that InvokeRequired is always false.  Better yet, you should get an exception that tells you that you can't use InvokeRequired on a form that hasn't been displayed yet.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using threads?

If your threads you have to invoke the parent form, not the msgbox itself.

```
Form frm = new Form();
if (parent.InvokeRequired)
{
    parent.Invoke(new ThreadStart(() =>
        {
            frm.ShowDialog();
        }));
}
else
{
    frm.ShowDialog();
}
```

If your working without threads just remove the invoke and explain a little what ShowMessage und msgbox do.

Answer (score 1):

try to use

```
Form.BringToFront();
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.control.bringtofront%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

What a mess in here!!

is MsgBox your custom type derived from Form class? if so, you can simply call its ShowDialog method to have it displayed modally.

If you can't, please share the content of the ShowMessage method.

Answer (score 0):

How do you call `ShowDialog`? You have to pass the main window (or any of its children) to the `ShowDialog` method, so it has a proper parent window.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how your ShowMsg and ShowMessage methods look like, but try this out:

```
msgBox = new MsgBox();
if (msgBox.InvokeRequired)
{
  msgBox.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate() { ShowMessage(); });
}
else
{
  ShowMessage();
}
```